# How to make form in _base.html

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I need to make form in header section of site. This form will be available for all pages in my site. For example, i have in my app "accounts":

**forms.py**

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('phone',)
```

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    form = SignupForm(request.POST or None)
    # CODE #
    ctx = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', ctx)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
]
```

**accounts/signup.html**

```
 {% block signup %}
     {{ form }}
 {% endblock %}
```

If I add`{% include 'accounts/signup.html' %}` to my _base.html, I don't, get form - {{ form }} but all other content will be included.

And can you tell me how exactly get form for all pages in site? Is it the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Use [a custom templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/) to initialize an empty form and display it from wherever you want - just make sure the `action` attribute of the HTML `<form>` tag points to your signup view.